# Changing Tab Order for Entry Input Dynamically in Xamarin

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, tabs

I have five entry controls and I want the tab order to change depending on certain conditions. For instance, sometimes I want the focus to go from entryA to entryB when tapping enter but other times I want it go from entryA to entryC.

I tried setting IsTabStop to a binded boolean from the viewmodel so that when it's set to false it skips that entry but it didn't work.

What else can I do to accomplish this?

```
<Entry x:Name="entryA" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="0"/>
<Entry x:Name="entryB" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="{Binding isTabStop}"/>
<Entry x:Name="entryC" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="2"/>
<Entry x:Name="entryD" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="3"/>
<Entry x:Name="entryE" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="4"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a **Completed** method in Entry to determine the enter operation. Then use **Focus** to set the focus.

Here is a small example for your reference:

Here is the xaml code(I only set the method in the first Entry):

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry x:Name="entryA" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="0" Completed="entryA_Completed"/>
    <Entry x:Name="entryB" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="1"/>
    <Entry x:Name="entryC" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="2"/>
    <Entry x:Name="entryD" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="3"/>
    <Entry x:Name="entryE" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="4"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the background code:

```
private void entryA_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //You can make some judgments
       entryC.Focus();//Select the third Entry
   }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option for me because it causes the keyboard to temporarily disappear then reappear. I need to seamlessly transition between inputs.

Comment: According to my test, my keyboard did not disappear.

Comment: Can you provide more information?